# App Development Localization Using Custom Fonts

Tags: android, ios, facebook, fonts

I'd like to localize an iOS and Android app for over 25 different languages using a custom font. The problem is no new fonts cover that type of ground. What's the current best practice for this problem in app development?

I've only come up with the following 2 solutions, however I'm unsure either are possible or a good idea.

1.) Hire a font designer to create a massive custom font across at least 3 different weights (regular, bold, italic). But that could be extremely costly considering the app license for some single-weight simplified Chinese fonts are 5k alone.

2.) Use a custom font that covers about 10 languages thanks to Latin characters (e.g. Proxima Nova) and then similar-looking fonts for unsupported languages.

It seems to me the current best practice is to use a custom font that covers a bulk of Latin-based languages and all unsupported languages fallback to the device fonts. But I've experienced problems there as well particularly with localizing dynamic third-party data from Facebook connect. If I'm in America and my friend in China has Chinese characters in their username a custom font outputs little square glyphs instead of falling back on the device's Chinese character set.

In any case both solutions add quite a bit of file size to the app which itself could be a deal-breaker. For solution 2 I've also considered using static images instead of embedding additional fonts, but that also presents a problem in localizing dynamic third-party data and creates a ton of work if the app should ever need updated.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The current best practice is to use the fonts that are embedded in the device.  Do you not like the look of the device fonts?  Why do you want a custom font?

Comment: Take a science fiction game for example, it makes more sense to use a custom, futuristic font than a device font. It helps the game experience feel more cohesive and less generic. That's just an example, but I think there are a lot of great reasons like that to use custom fonts in app development.

Comment: There are many great reasons.. but do you have one :) the question is are you over complicating this for yourself.  I am an Android developer, so I can't speak to iOS, but in Android, since 4.0, the system has shipped with pretty good coverage in language fonts. When you use them you gain the advantage of being able to mix char sets and let the system pick the font for you.  To do that on your own is very complicated and few people do it.

Comment: I've created apps with support for over 70 languages in custom fonts, the way I did it is to embed multiple custom fonts in the app, but that will break down if you have Chinese and farsi in the same textview.  You can inspect each character and determine which font set to use and use a span to change individual characters font.. but its quite difficult.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right to question my need. I'm trying to find the balance and I understand that's a bit subjective.

How do you feel about the amount of file size that's added to the download in embedding so many custom fonts? And it sounds like the best way to approach areas where third-party dynamic data is an issue is to simply rely on device fonts.

Is it safe to say that my solution 1 is extremely rare in the development community, and that solution 2 is more of a best practice?

Thanks for your input, seriously.

Comment: Solution 2 is more practical than solution 1 for most people.  If you don't know what character set the the text is in, custom fonts are hard to deal with but you may want to check out AntiSquare to see how they handle it: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Antisquare